What do the food allergy numbers with letters (e.g., 1a) mean in the Czech Republic?
Due to the EU regulation, a lot/most restaurant menus in the EU have food allergy indicators, and in the Czech Republic they have very conveniently standardized based on the list in Annex II of the regulation (as far as was able to find out at least). Sometimes there are letters attached to the number, for example 1a. My current assumption is that the food has the exception listed in that section of the annex. So continuing with the example of 1a, I am assuming that would mean a food marked with 1a contains wheat based glucose syrups including dextrose but not Cereals containing gluten, namely: wheat, rye, barley, oats, spelt, kamut or their hybridised strains, and products thereof
Can anyone confirm my theory or tell me what something like 1a actually means?
Excerpt from annex II:


Cereals containing gluten, namely: wheat, rye, barley, oats, spelt, kamut or their hybridised strains, and products thereof, except:

(a) wheat based glucose syrups including dextrose (1);
(b) wheat based maltodextrins (1);
(c) glucose syrups based on barley;
(d) cereals used for making alcoholic distillates including ethyl
alcohol of agricultural origin;

Update 1:
The allergen numbers do not always have letters. Forms I have seen include:

(3)
(3/5)
(8d)
(1a/4/6/8d)


Does the menu have footnotes that explain what '1a' is? That is how it is often done.

@MarkJohnson Not on any of the menus I have seen with the number and letter combinations so far.

Reading the german version of this excerpt, I came to the conclusion that a, b, c and d are ingredients that are not considered to be allergens, so using "1a" to indicate that a food contains a non-allergen seems useless. But this might be totally off, as I have no idea what 1a could mean instead...

Have you seen any other letters attached, but a? Sabine is right, that point 1(a) of the annex contains exceptions to category 1, so your initial assumption does not really make sense. The allergens are some times referred to as A1, A2, A3 etc., A probably just being an abbreviation of Czech 'alergen', perhaps 1a, 2a, 3a does not mean anything more than that as well, but that would also not make sense, if you"ve ever seen other letters than a. Example: https://blog.foreigners.cz/standardized-allergy-charts-in-prague/

Yes, I have found other letters e.g. (1a/3/7/8d). Updating the main question with this information.

After asking a few establishments I received generic* answers about the letters denoting the type of allergen (e.g. type of nut - peanut, walnut, etc.). I was never provided any specific answers, like 8d meaning the food contains peanuts, so I don't know if there is consistent meaning or if it is establishment specific.
*Without a common language between us communication was limited.
